# I used sae 30 instead of 5w30

Tags: engine, oil

I put two quartz of sae 30 and now I'm having problems with changing gears they take longer. What can I do to take it all out and put the right oil. If you can please help me thank you.

Comment: Drain it out, replace it with the correct stuff, run it for a few days then drain and refill again...